# Can I unlock the 'Hardware Enthusiast' Badge with a PS3 controller in MotioninJoy?

Tags: steam, motioninjoy-ds3tool

I'm having a little trouble earning the 'Hardware Enthusiast' Badge - the only requirement I have left is to launch a game through Big Picture with a controller.

I have my PS3 controller connected to my computer and I am running MotioninJoy with it emulating an Xbox 360 controller.

What i've tried (any action taken was with the controller)

- I enabled and navigated Steam Big Picture
- Launched Team Fortress 2 & I played a round or two
- Exited TF2 and launched Portal 1.
- Smashed through the test chambers.
- Exited Portal

But somehow I still haven't earned the badge. I thought I might give it 24 hours to tick over, but still nothing. I've also tried exiting Steam and starting it up in Big Picture mode to begin with (tried TF2 again), but still no luck.

Is there something I'm missing here?

The games I've tried so far:

- Team Fortress 2  (partial controller support)
- Portal (partial support)
- The Stanley Parable (full controller support)
- Left 4 Dead 2 (full support)

Comment: I got mine for simply opening a game and closing it with my controller. I'm not sure how motioninjoy works, but if it emulates keyboard events when you use the controller, it probably won't work.

Comment: @3ventic - its set to emulate an Xbox 360 controller - I.e. steam thinks its an 'x-input' device. I Also checked out the button mappings, they're all gamepad buttons - no keyboard or mouse

Comment: Then it should work just fine, indeed.

Comment: Did you actually use the controller within Big Picture to launch the game? I did it with a 360 controller by opening big picture, using the 360 controller to choose TF2, played a round or so, then closed it with the controller (I think).

Comment: Did you try any games with "full controller support"? http://store.steampowered.com/search/#category1=998&category2=28 - I doubt that's it, but it's a thought. Like Gray said, just set steam to Big Picture, navigate using the controller to launch a game, play it for a tick and then close it and you should get it. It almost makes me wonder if maybe it was a time-limited badge...

Comment: @Gray - all actions taken were with the controller

Comment: @skovacs1 - tf2 and Portal aren't on that list, that could be it. Let me confirm when I get home - I'll try the Stanley parable (which is on the list)

Comment: @skovacs1 - Nope, tried the Stanley Parable and Left 4 Dead 2- both tout 'full controller support' - both ran fine, controller worked correctly :/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably could have unlocked it with motionJoy if you had done so earlier.

As per the [SteamMachines page](http://store.steampowered.com/livingroom/SteamMachines/):

> On October 25th, the list will be locked. So complete the quest before then!

Since that date has come and gone, you seem to have missed your chance.

Comment: Damn. I travelled 2 hours to pick up my PS3 for nothing :/

Comment: It only says that for level 2 - "Steam Hardware Beta Candidate". It doesn't say the same for level 1, where the associated task is.

Comment: @AdamV On the quest page, correct. On the linked SteamMachines page however, it lists all tasks as part of the eligibility quest and then says the quoted line. The reference is vague on whether the badge becomes unavailable or just the second level or just the beta candidacy. Given how the OP tried every step necessary to achieve this (steps that worked for me using a non-360 controller emulating x-input), I conclude that the badge might no longer be achievable. It is certainly still unclear and warrants further investigation. http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/684839199118107983/

Comment: The entire badge progress panel has since been removed it seems - I cant see it anywhere